# How to join the graph points using curve or arc

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am using highcharts to make a graph . My graph is look like below,
[image: My Graph]

I want to merge the points using an Arc or Curve. So my excepted output look like below,

[image]

Also i am using PlotLines to draw a line in Yaxis. I want to mark the point in  the PlotLine . I am using the following code to make this graph .

```
$(document).ready(function () {


var left = [[4,7],[9,2]];
var right = [[2,2],[9,9]];


Highcharts.chart('container', {



title:{
    text:''
},

tooltip: { enabled: false },      

exporting: { enabled: false },

credits: {enabled: false},


plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointStart: 1

    }
},

xAxis: {
    max: 10,
    min: 1,
    tickInterval: 1
},

 yAxis: {
    max: 11,
    min: 0,
    tickInterval: 1,

    plotLines: [{
        color: 'black', 
        value: 5.5,
        width: 2

    }],

},



series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: left
},
{
    showInLegend: false,
    data: right
},

],


});

});
```

Comment: You can use [renderer.path](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.path) to draw a path from one point to another. The values can be translated to pixels with the use of axis.toPixels() - see example http://jsfiddle.net/r0j46wn6/

Comment: how can i change the curve dynamically based on center line ( plotline )

Comment: How should curves depend on the plot line?

Comment: Curve is joined based on  my plot line  points

Comment: Can you please check this. - http://jsfiddle.net/r0j46wn6/18/ @ morganfree. I am make this using static point . But i want to change this as dynamically based on the left ,right , center data's

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamically based'?

Comment: In my script , variables  ( left ,right , center is changed as dynamically.

Comment: But you still change them to some values, so use them in the callback. Also, you have access to the points from the chart inside the load callback - this.series is an array of series, this.series[0].data is an array of points - from the data rray you can access all your points from the chart and use them to calculate paths.